# Assimilate details from 2 map into a third map

Tags: java, java-8

I have 2 map `item<String, ItemDetails>`  and `Price<String , UnitDetails>`
For a filtered list of items,I need to populate some price details into another map

```
ItemSummary< String, Indent>
```

Illustration:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, ItemDetails> entry : item.entrySet()) {
        if("something".equals(entry.getValue().getDescription())
        && "available".equals(entry.getValue().getStock())){
            UnitDetails unit = Price.get(entry.getKey());
            ItemSummary.put(entry.getKey(), new Indent(unit.getUnit(), unit.getPrice())
        }
```

How do I achieve this using stream, filter and map

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
ItemSummary<String,Indent> summary =
    item.entrySet()
        .stream()
        .filter(e -> "something".equals(e.getValue().getDescription())
                     && "available".equals(e.getValue().getStock()))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,
                                  e -> {UnitDetails unit = Price.get(e.getKey()); 
                                        return new Indent(unit.getUnit(), unit.getPrice());
                                       }));
```

If a `UnitDetails` instance contains a property whose value is the same as the corresponding key in the `Map<String , UnitDetails>` map, you can make the `collect` step cleaner:

```
ItemSummary<String,Indent> summary =
    item.entrySet()
        .stream()
        .filter(e -> "something".equals(e.getValue().getDescription())
                     && "available".equals(e.getValue().getStock()))
        .map(e -> Price.get(e.getKey()))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Unit::getKey,
                                  u -> new Indent(u.getUnit(), u.getPrice())));
```